# How to initialize BufferedImage fast in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, bufferedimage

I have the following Java code:

```
public static BufferedImage createImage(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
  BufferedImage res = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

  byte[] rdata = ((DataBufferByte)res.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    int yi = y * width;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      rdata[yi] = data[yi];
      yi++;
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

In C++ I would use memcpy, but in Java?

Or maybe it is possible to initialize the result image with the passed data directly?

Comment: How much faster do you need it to be?

Comment: No exact number, I just new that this way is slow and I want the code to be faster/better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, to copy the array quickly you can use `System.arraycopy`:

```
System.arraycopy(data, 0, rdata, 0, height * width);
```

I don't know about initializing the `BufferedImage` to start with though, I'm afraid.

Have you tried:

```
res.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, data);
```

?

Comment: I just tried both of your solutions and they work great!
Thanks!